# $k$-cells vs closed ball in proofs

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a beginner in real analysis. I'm studying from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and I got confused in the way that $k$-cells can be used in proofs.  I see that a $k$-cell is basically an interval in higher dimensions, which is a convenient set when I need to prove closure, compactess, and boundedness. However, I wonder if I could equivalently use a closed ball in some cases e.g. Heine-Borel Theorem proof.

Comment: You could show that closed balls are compact although I'm not aware of a proof as easy as for $k$-cells. Notice that these are easy to work with since you have a higher analog of the nested intervals theorem. Since every closed and bounded ball is a closed subset of a $k$-cell, it must also be compact as Rudin shows. This is the standard way of proceeding.